# Check if numbers are all different

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I don't usually use VB and I'm having something that would usually seem trivial.
I want to check 3 numbers, and if they are all different then that means the triangle is infact 'scalene'
But my current logic statement refuses to work;

```
If First <> Second & Second <> Third & First <> Third Then
MsgBox("The triangle is scalene")
end if
```

I have tired weird ways of fixing it and done plenty of searching but for some r reason it never works.

Comment: I sounds like you're not running your code with `Option Strict On`. You should always do that. If you had you would have gotten a compile error - `"Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'String' to 'Boolean'."`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `&` operator is for string concatenation in VB, not Boolean logic.  Instead, use `And` or preferably `AndAlso`:

```
If First <> Second AndAlso Second <> Third AndAlso First <> Third Then
```

Comment: Worked, will select properly when it allows, thank you.